# Protected by Community for a simple question

Tags: support, protected-questions

Why has the question *[How do I do an SQL query based on a foreign key field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40210990/how-to-do-sql-query-based-on-foreign-key-field#40211030)* been protected by Community?

[image]

Is that a bug or really community found it very useful?

Comment: After a certain number of answers on a question get flagged as spam, the question is automatically protected to prevent more spam.

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat However, in this case, there do not appear to be any spam posts, deleted or otherwise. Just 2 more repeat answers, deleted by their owners before the lock. It appears to have been locked at the same time this answer was posted: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40211253/3155639

Comment: As the answer to the dupe says, it got auto protected after the [fifth answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40211253/447356) from a low rep (<10) user has been posted.